# Date Range filter is not working when Parsing from JSON request

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to filter the data on date range but I am getting null data.
I have a get query and sending the search criteria as encoded data and decoding before fire the find request.

Here is the code:

```
localhost:3016/api/bomReport?filter=%7B%22reportType%22%3A%22detail%22%2C%22createdDate%22%3A%7B%22%24gte%22%3A%20ISODate%28%272017-06-20T05%3A50%3A31.202Z%27%29%2C%20%22%24lt%22%3AISODate%28%272017-06-21T05%3A54%3A08.367Z%27%29%7D%7D

{"reportType":"detail","createdDate":{"$gte": ISODate('2017-06-20T05:50:31.202Z'), "$lt":ISODate('2017-06-21T05:54:08.367Z')}}

var queryString = decodeURI(req.query.filter);
    console.log(queryString);
    var query = JSON.parse(queryString); 

 BOMReport.find(query).populate(opts).exec(function(err, result) {
```

But I am not able to parse the data. Getting the error.

Please tell me how can I do the searching.

Comment: Are you actually passing in the string `"ISODate('2017-06-20T05:50:31.202Z')"`? If so then that is completely wrong. You should only be passing in the ISOString itself `'2017-06-20T05:50:31.202Z'`. And the question is about JSON parsing and has nothing to do with the tags or title you chose.

Comment: Thanks, it is working for me..:)